# How to have different return values in each describe block for a service mock with angular testbed and jest?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

When testing components or services, I would like to test different scenarios: the service returns one kind of object, it returns an error, it returns a different kind of object, etc. But I'm having issues making this happen with jest and angular.

This is what I have:

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let rootElement: DebugElement;

  const mockdata = {
    name: 'Foo',
    surname: 'Bar',
  };

  let mockServiceInstance: { [key: string]: jest.Mock } = {
    getName: jest.fn(),
    getSurname: jest.fn(),
  };

  let mockService: jest.Mock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // These values are always used throughout the test suite
    // no matter what.
    mockServiceInstance.getNamee.mockReturnValue('');
    mockServiceInstance.getSurname.mockReturnValue('');

    mockService = jest
      .fn()
      .mockReturnValue(mockServiceInstance);
  });

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MyService,
          useClass: mockService,
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    rootElement = fixture.debugElement;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('when there is a name and surname', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // These values are never returned.
      mockServiceInstance.getName.mockReturnValue('Foo')
      mockServiceInstance.getSurname.mockReturnValue('Bar');

      TestBed.overrideProvider(MyService, {
        useFactory: mockService,
      });
    });

    it("should show the name", () => {
      const expected = 'Foo';

      const actual = rootElement.query(By.css('#name'))
        .nativeElement.textContent;

      expect(actual).toBe(expected);
    });

    it("should show the surname", () => {
      const expected = 'Bar';

      const actual = rootElement.query(By.css('#surname'))
        .nativeElement.textContent;

      expect(actual).toBe(expected);
    });
  });

  describe('when there is a name and no surname', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // These values are never returned.
      mockServiceInstance.getName.mockReturnValue('Foo')
      mockServiceInstance.getSurname.mockReturnValue('');

      TestBed.overrideProvider(MyService, {
        useFactory: mockService,
      });
    });

    it("should show the name", () => {
      const expected = 'Foo';

      const actual = rootElement.query(By.css('#name'))
        .nativeElement.textContent;

      expect(actual).toBe(expected);
    });

    it("should not show the surname", () => {
      const expected = '';

      const actual = rootElement.query(By.css('#surname'))
        .nativeElement.textContent;

      expect(actual).toBe(expected);
    });
  });
});
```

My problem is that whatever override I set for the return values is never run, it runs the implementation from the topmost `beforeEach` instead, every time.

I suspect this doesn't work because the mock service is injected and instantiated once and then reused... But I thought `Testbed.overrideProvider` would inject the new instance and use these values instead. I have also tried `useValue` instead of `useFactory` in the options but no difference.

I have also considered using the parameters the mock is called with to return different values but that isn't as elegant since it all has to be defined in one place for every scenarion; and there are cases where I can't directly control the arguments the mocked service is called with from the test.

How can I elegantly achieve selective overrides for the service's mock functions return values to test different scenarios within the same test suite?

Comment: overrideProvider in nested beforeEach cannot affect anything because you already instantiated a component in parent beforeEach.

Comment: Back to square one then. How do I achieve this in an elegant way while testing?

Comment: Move the contents of beforeEach that has createComponent to helper function and call it directly from tests. It should be executed after all beforeEach.